# Pass variable from middleware to templates

Tags: django, variables, middleware

I'm Django starter. So far I learned pass variable from *view* to *template*. But now I need pass variable to my main layout. I can pass it in each page's def in view. But its too much duplication. So I started learn about middleware.

I created middlewares.py and included it in settings. In middlewares.py file, how to pass variable to my main layout?

Below is my current middlewares.py content, I tried many ways and commented them out, because not working.

```
from django.db import connections
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

class NotificationsMiddleware(object):
    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):

        request.context_data['notification_count'] = 2
        response = view_func(request, *view_args, **view_kwargs)

        return response

    # def process_request(self, request):
    #     request.notification_count = 2
    #     return

    # def process_template_response(self, request, response):
    #     # response.context['notification_count'] = 2
    #     response.context_data['notification_count'] = 2
    #     # return response
    #     return render(request, 'main/locations.html')
```

Comment: I'm not understanding why you accepted an answer that provides the solution in a `context processor`, you asked specifically how to do this in `middleware`

Comment: Like I said I was starter meantime :)

Comment: Yeah, I got that and no worries. Haha this was just a perfect post title to solve my issue recently. I figured it out through the docs, but I was not expecting a Context Procesor to be the main solution here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may create a template context processor, first create a python file with a method that returns a dictionary with the info you need then add the route to this file in your project settings, using your example:

create a file *context_processors.py* on your app:

```
 from myapp.models import MyModel

 def my_context(request):
    context_data = dict()
    context_data['notification_count'] = MyModel.objects.all().count()
    return context_data
```

The add the context processor in your *settings.py*

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    #  ...
    'myapp.context_proccessors.my_context',
)
```

The you can use the 'variable' in any template:

```
<p>Count: {{ notification_count }}</p>
```

Comment: Its not always return 2. I need read it from database then return row count as number. Also must return row sooner or later. Can template context do it?

Comment: You can import the model in your context processors file and change the number 2 by anything ;)

Comment: Since Django 1.8 TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS is deprecated. Actual add 'myapp.context_proccessors.my_contex' into the 'context_processors' option in the OPTIONS of a DjangoTemplates backend instead. See docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#template-context-processors

Answer (score 3):

You can define a `context processor` function and add it to `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` list defined in **settings.py**.

Let's assume you have a file named *project/context_processors.py*, you can create a function that basically passes your value to all templates.

```
def notification_count(request):
    return {'notification_count': 2}
```

*settings.py*

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    ...
    'context_proccessors.notification_count',
)
```

Calling `{{notification_count}}` in your template will return 2.

You can take a look at the official [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/api/) for more info about context processors.

---

Second approach would be, as you said, using middleware. However, I think that would be an overkill since you can do much more complicated calculations via middlewares.

*middlewares.py*

```
class NotificationsMiddleware(object):
    def process_template_response(self, request, response):
        if not ('notification_count' in response.context_data):
            response.context_data['notification_count'] = 2
        return response
```

Please note that, you should add the middleware into `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` list defined in your settings file.

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES += ('middlewares.NotificationsMiddleware',)
```

Please see the middleware [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/middleware/#process-template-response) for more information on how to alter request-response cycle in Django framework.

Hope this helps.

Comment: 1. I followed your context_processor method. But there is error:
Put 'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth' in your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS setting in order to use the admin application.

Comment: If there is already a `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` list defined in your settings, add your context processor to it instead of the one imported from `django.conf.global_settings`. In other words, delete this line `from django.conf.global_settings import TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` and try again. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Well done for showing an example with Middleware as the OP asked.

Answer (score 3):

Middleware allows you to bind data to the `request`, meaning if you use Middleware and not a Context Processor, you can access this **universal variable data** in both templates and views, or actually anywhere where a `request` object is used throughout your codebase.

In my mind, this makes Middleware superior to Context Processors if you actually need a universal variable that is available everywhere. In short, and according to the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/middleware/ Middleware is called on every view call.

Here is a simple example using your code and Middleware

```
class NotificationsMiddleware(object):

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):

        # I am showing this as a standard var not a dict as you originally had it, 
        # for simplicity, this is now a request attribute called notification_count
        request.notification_count = 2

        response = self.get_response(request)

        return response

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        # You don't need this method for the middleware to work anymore
        # with Django as the __call__ method covers it, so you can delete it.
        pass
```

Now pass the Custom Middleware to settings like so:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    # custom middleware
    '[YOUR-PATH].NotificationsMiddleware'
]
```

Now you can call the variable in any template like so:

```
{{ request.notification_count }}
```

Or in any view, like so:

```
def index(request):

    print(' Notification Count =', request.notification_count)
    ...
    return render(request, 'index.html', { })
```